# How to change the addTuioCursor() implementation with processing?

Tags: processing, multi-touch, tuio

I am currently working on a small multi-touch game using the processing language with the TUIO library.
I want to manually set the CursorID depending on which half of the screen the cursor is added and since the only time the method is called it just prints a message as seen below.

```
// called when a cursor is added to the scene
void addTuioCursor(TuioCursor tcur) {
  if (verbose) println("add cur "+tcur.getCursorID()+" ("+tcur.getSessionID()+ ") " +tcur.getX()+" "+tcur.getY());
  //redraw();
}
```

I searched a bit around but I wasn't able to find anything. Is there a way to change the implementation of the addTuioCursor() method?

Answer (score 1):

You should still be able to set do add your logic on top of it.
For example you would have your separate list of custom cursor IDs which you update based on the TuioCursor event.

This is just an illustration, assuming you have an `ArrayList` of `Integer` to add your custom ID:

```
// called when a cursor is added to the scene
void addTuioCursor(TuioCursor tcur) {
  if (verbose) println("add cur "+tcur.getCursorID()+" ("+tcur.getSessionID()+ ") " +tcur.getX()+" "+tcur.getY());
  // if newly added cursor is on the left half of the screen
  if(tcur.getX() < width / 2){
    // set a custom ID
    int customID = (int)random(0,100);
    // add a custom ID
    //leftCursorsList.add(customID);
  }
}
```

This is intself might not be super youself: you may want to make your custom cursor class to hold not just the ID, but perhaps the x,y or a reference to the `TuioCursor`, whatever serves your end goal. There is nothing stopping you from manageing your own list of custom cursor data based on TUIO events.